# How can I use "hints" in runtime optimization?

Tags: osrm

The OSRM Routing engine returns "hints" in many of its outputs, and you are able to pass these back into a new request, which saves on lookup time and thereby optimizes the query.

My question is how do I pass these "hints" back into the

```
/table/v1/car
```

API call as per the example below?

EXAMPLE:

An OSRM API request of

```
   /table/v1/car/-0.693000,52.078000;-0.724000,52.040000
```

gives back (snippet) :

> "sources": [
> {
> "hint": "uImugOqJroBBAAAAAAAAALoBAAAAAAAA7WvYQQAAAACaUzhDAAAAAEEAAAAAAAAAugEAAAAAAAAXCgAAmXb1__mxGgP4bPX_sKUaAwYALwrjJ41R",
> "distance": 388.619802,
> "location": [
> -0.690535,
> 52.081145
> ],
> "name": ""
> },

The original coordinates:
-0.693000, 52.078000
have been fixed up to:
-0.690535, 52.081145

(snapped to a nearby road and the hint is as above).

So I would like to utilise these "hints" in a new API query for the same LAT/LNG location, which should optimize the query.

The manual says about hints:

> This can be used on subsequent request to significantly speed up the query and to connect multiple services.

I've tried various combinations and looking at the manual, but so far nothing has worked.

- Has anybody successfully passed "hint" data into the /table/v1/car
  API for OSRM Routing?
- If so, please would you let me know what you did

Comment: I don't know OSRM, and I could be totally off-base here, but couldn't it be as simple as replacing the `-0.693000,52.078000` in your original query with `-0.690535, 52.081145` for your subsequent requests? The optimization would seem to be that it doesn't have to do the work of adjusting the coordinates on the subsequent requests.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for your comment and yes I've tried that and various combinations of to no avail. It is surely something trivial yet it alludes me.

Comment: I see what you mean. I could try that. I suspect there are other optimizations as well however this could resolve "snap to grid" time. I will try it in the meantime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your request:
/table/v1/car/-0.693000,52.078000;-0.724000,52.040000
and got response:

{"code":"Ok",
"durations":[[0,596.2],[615.9,0]],"destinations":[
{"hint":"teJ0h-fidIdBAAAAAAAAALoBAAAAAAAA7WvYQQAAAACaUzhDAAAAAEEAAAAAAAAAugEAAAAAAACrkAAAmXb1__mxGgP4bPX_sKUaAwYALwr88AjE",
"distance":388.619802,"name":"","location":[-0.690535,52.081145]},{"hint":"dbcDgLevA4BpAAAAAAAAAAQGAAAwCAAA4-dpQQAAAACIYVZDGSCSQzQAAAAAAAAAAgMAABwEAACrkAAATvb0_48VGgPg8_T_QBEaAw4Afwf88AjE",
"distance":129.943557,"name":"","location":[-0.723378,52.041103]}],
"sources":[
{"hint":"teJ0h-fidIdBAAAAAAAAALoBAAAAAAAA7WvYQQAAAACaUzhDAAAAAEEAAAAAAAAAugEAAAAAAACrkAAAmXb1__mxGgP4bPX_sKUaAwYALwr88AjE",
"distance":388.619802,"name":"","location":[-0.690535,52.081145]},{"hint":"dbcDgLevA4BpAAAAAAAAAAQGAAAwCAAA4-dpQQAAAACIYVZDGSCSQzQAAAAAAAAAAgMAABwEAACrkAAATvb0_48VGgPg8_T_QBEaAw4Afwf88AjE",
"distance":129.943557,"name":"","location":[-0.723378,52.041103]}]}

Your request has 2 points, so you have to add 2 hints, one for each point.

So, the request with hints is:

/table/v1/car/-0.693000,52.078000;-0.724000,52.040000?hints=teJ0h-fidIdBAAAAAAAAALoBAAAAAAAA7WvYQQAAAACaUzhDAAAAAEEAAAAAAAAAugEAAAAAAACrkAAAmXb1__mxGgP4bPX_sKUaAwYALwr88AjE;dbcDgLevA4BpAAAAAAAAAAQGAAAwCAAA4-dpQQAAAACIYVZDGSCSQzQAAAAAAAAAAgMAABwEAACrkAAATvb0_48VGgPg8_T_QBEaAw4Afwf88AjE

where hints are separated by semicolon.

Comment: Thank you for that, I have not tested it yet however it looks good. This is still relevant to me but this question had such low responses. I will mark as an answer currently.